# Error with homestead when try to vagrant up

Tags: laravel, homestead

Actually I'm trying to use Laravel Homestead on Windows.

When I try to make the `vagrant up` I get this error:

```
C:/Users/Lluis/Homestead/scripts/homestead.rb:125:in `configure': undefined method `each' for "\u00D4\u00C7\u00F6 ~/.ssh/id_rsa":String (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Users/Lluis/Homestead/Vagrantfile:35:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/v2/loader.rb:37:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:119:in `block in load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:116:in `load'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/vagrantfile.rb:28:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:810:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:810:in `vagrantfile'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:556:in `host'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:214:in `block in action_runner'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:33:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:543:in `hook'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:792:in `unload'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/bin/vagrant:141:in `ensure in <main>'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-2.0.1/bin/vagrant:141:in `<main>'
```

I read in others questions it's a error cause can't found the .ssh files.

I check my homestead.yaml file but think all it's good I will put here the file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: c:/Users/Lluis/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
     — c:/Users/Lluis/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: d:/Homestead_Projects
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/Laravel/public   

databases:
    - homestead
```

How can I fix the error? Someone see some error on homestead.yaml file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if in home directory ~, There is an old directory .vagrant and .vagrant.d, you have to delete these and add the laravel/homestead box again.
cheers!

Comment: I have 2 folders like you say .vagrant and .vagrant.d , for be sure this is not the problem I delete the two folders and now adding the laravel/homestead box again. Give me a few minuts

Comment: Same error, I think this is not the problem. The problem must be something about SSH :/

Comment: Did u checked permissions?